# Express the set $\{3, \{3\}, \{\{3\}\}, \{\{\{3\}\}\}, \dots \}$ in set-builder notation.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to express the set $\{3, \{3\}, \{\{3\}\}, \{\{\{3\}\}\}, \dots \}$ containing all sets of the form $$\underbrace{\{\dots\{}_{n} 3 \underbrace{\}\cdots\}}_{n}$$ for finite $n\geq 0$, in set-builder notation? Furthermore, is it possible to do it in a non-recursive way?

Comment: The set? Or the elements of the set?

Comment: The set itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty common way would be $$\{x:\forall y((3\in y\wedge \forall z(z\in y\Rightarrow \{z\}\in y))\Rightarrow x\in y)\},$$ meaning "the set of all things that are in every set containing $3$ and closed under $x\mapsto \{x\}$".

Comment: I wouldn't call this _common_, but it's probably the neatest way to do it without needing auxiliary definitions.

Comment: (+1) Maybe it would also be worth mentioning that essentially you are saying that $x$ is contained in the intersection of all such $y$ and every such $y$ must contain $\{3, \{3\}, \{\{3\}\}, \ldots\}$ as a subset.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Perhaps; I did learn set theory from odd sources. It is the primary way I have seen it presented solely (well, almot) in set-builder notation.

Comment: @Qudit - Good point, next time I get a few minutes I'll add a short elaboration to that effect.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: I agree this is the most straightforward way to do it _under the given constraints_ where we specifically want a single self-contained formula to stick into a set builder. I was merely questioning whether it is "common" to want to do it under those constraints in the first place -- the OP probably cannot expect that a random reader would be able to decipher this easily, compared to defining an auxiliary function from $\mathbb N$ and use Replacement on that rather than comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F:V\rightarrow V$ such that $F(x)=\{x\}$. Then define by recursion:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
F_0(x) &= &x \\
F_{n+1}(x) & = & \{F_n(x)\}
\end{array}
$$

so, the set in $\{F_n(3):n\in\omega\}$

Comment: Thanks! Any idea whether it's possible to have a non-recursive definition?

Comment: Didn't the OP ask for a non-recursive solution?